# xpath 1.0 set the value of non existent attribute

Tags: xpath

I have a xml document

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-16"?>
<APIDATA xmlns="api-com">
<ORDER EngineID="1" OrderID="66" OtherInfo="100"><INSTSPECIFIER InstID="27" SeqID="17"/>     
</ORDER>
<ORDER EngineID="2" OrderID="67" OtherInfo="200"><INSTSPECIFIER InstID="28" SeqID="18"/>    
</ORDER>
<ORDER EngineID="3" OrderID="68"><INSTSPECIFIER InstID="29" SeqID="19"/></ORDER>
</APIDATA>
```

How do i get the value of OtherInfo attribute using xpath 
but when it does not exist i want Null to be returned

If i used the following xpath /APIDATA/ORDER/@OtherInfo i get the output as

```
100
200
```

But since for OrderID 68 the OtherInfo is missing i want the output to be

```
100
200
0
```

There is a post here which is close to my solution but i somehow cant get it to work
[Can I create a value for a missing tag in XPath?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40361/can-i-create-a-value-for-a-missing-tag-in-xpath)

Comment: AFAIK, I don't think this is directly doable... you can ask xpath to return true or false, and let you program logic return null or otherwise accordingly...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately, the approach in the *answer to the linked question* only work if there is only one value to be returned from a given XML document (see below for a demo on this point). So given the XML sample posted in this question, short answer would be ***this can't be done using pure XPath 1.0***.

If the XPath is used within a programming language, one possible approach would be, to use XPath expression that always return a value, for example `/APIDATA/ORDER`. Then, for each `<ORDER>` element returned, usually there are plenty of options to get `OtherInfo` attribute and provide default value in case the attribute is not found.

---

Applying the linked post approach to your case would results in the following XPath expression :

```
substring(concat("0", //ORDER[3]/@OtherInfo), 2 * number(boolean(//ORDER[3]/@OtherInfo)))
```

The XPath successfully return `0` when applied to the 3rd `<ORDER>` element which doesn't have attribute `OtherInfo`, see the demo* : [`xpathtester`](http://www.xpathtester.com/xpath/c939ea2c026438bf033d42bf19bad9b0), [`xpatheval`](http://xpatheval.apphb.com/R70Q65v8W)

<sub>default namespace has been removed in the demo for the sake of simplifying the XPath</sub>

---

Implementation of the same approach in XSLT 1.0, as requested :

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" xmlns:d="api-com">
  <xsl:output method="text" indent="yes"/>

  <xsl:template match="d:ORDER">
    <xsl:value-of select="substring(concat('0', @OtherInfo), 2 * number(boolean(@OtherInfo)))"/>
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

output :

```
100
200
0
```

Demo : [`xpathtester`](http://www.xpathtester.com/xslt/389da35b190e6fcf04d93120a209c8c3)

Comment: Thanks har07 for taking a look at this and helping me out.Can i do this using XSLT ?